# Calling a stored package from informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement to run an existing package after data load in source tables for package is complete. I know I can use a Stored Procedure Transformation to call the package. However, there are no input or output parameters defined in the package, and I can't edit the package either, as it is being used in a lot of other processes.

Is there a way to call a stored procedure transformation which has no input and output parameters defined in the stored package? Please advise.

Comment: can you put it inside a shell script and call it as post session success command. May be it will be much easier that put it into a mapping and attach it to every workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Post SQL` option. It's available in your session. Go to `Mapping` tab and check the properties of the applicable target transformation.